# Adafruit Neopixel 60LED RGBW Strip showing up with wrong RGB color

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3b+, led, adafruit

We are currently using the Adafruit Neopixel RGBW 60 pixel LED strip with our project, and are currently trying to control it. The strip, however, is displaying incorrect colors when trying to directly control them. Here is how it is being controlled:

```py
import board
import neopixel

pixel_pin = board.D18

num_pixels = 60

order = neopixel.RGBW

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, num_pixels, brightness=0.5, auto_write=false, pixel_order = order)

for i in range(num_pixels):
    pixels[i] = (15, 72, 121, 0)

pixels.show()
```

This is the color we are expecting:

[image: Expected RGB color]

However, this is the color we are getting out of the RGB strip:
[image: wrong color actual color]

It's hard to tell from the picture, but the LEDs are outputting a light purple instead of a dark blue like requested via rgb. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The model of LEDs are P2846A

Comment: Perhaps you could experiment with the color. Perhaps subtracting a little green and adding that to the blue?

Comment: @NomadMaker Yeah I can play with the values to get it right, I was just more concerned that the inputted colors aren't displaying correctly

Comment: What do red 255,0,0 green 0,255,0 and blue 0,0,255 output?

Comment: @Tmello225 - different monitors and LEDs display different colors for the same input. I agree with CoderMike.

Comment: @CoderMike With the order at RGBW, 255, 0, 0, 0 emits green, and with the order at GRBW and 255, 0, 0, 0, the LEDs emits red. This may be a wiring issue.